# Flutter error: Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt (The following UnsupportedError was thrown during paint():)

Tags: flutter

everyone.

So, I'm facing with this error:
flutter: The following UnsupportedError was thrown during paint():
flutter: Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt
(You can see the entire log on the screenshots)

Basically, I have an application composed by tabs, my "TabsScreen" class is my main class, with allows me to switch between tabs. The problem comes when I'm on my "RatingScreen" and then I select the "TextFormField" inside it, if I select the text form field and then I decide to switch to another tab flutter throws me the error that I mentioned.
(I post the workflow on the screenshots, they are ordered so you can see the steps I follow until I get the error)

```
class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  User userInfo;

  TabsScreen(Map<String, User> userInfoArgs) {
    this.userInfo = userInfoArgs["userProfileInfo"];
  }

  @override
  _TabsScreenState createState() => _TabsScreenState();
}

class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  ///Attributes
  int _tabsNumber = 3;
  int _selectedTabIndex = 0;
  TabController _tabController;

  ///Methods
  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: _tabsNumber);

    _tabController.addListener(() {
      _selectedTabIndex = _tabController.index;

      setState(() {});
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(64), 
        child: Header(userImageURL: widget.userInfo.userImage, userRating: widget.userInfo.rating),
      ),
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: _tabsNumber, 
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[ 
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.grey, 
                  width: 1
                )
              )
            ),
            height: screenHeight * 0.075,
            child: TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              indicatorColor: Color(0xFF4599E1),
              tabs: <Widget> [
                Tab(
                  icon: _selectedTabIndex  == 0 
                  ? Container(child: Image.asset("assets/images/HomeIconSelected.png"), height: screenHeight * 0.041,) 
                  : Container(child: Image.asset("assets/images/HomeIconUnselected.png"), height: screenHeight * 0.041,)
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: _selectedTabIndex == 1
                  ? Container(child: Image.asset("assets/images/RatingIconSelected.png"), height: screenHeight * 0.056,)
                  : Container(child: Image.asset("assets/images/RatingIconUnselected.png"), height: screenHeight * 0.056,)
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: _selectedTabIndex == 2
                  ? Container(child: Image.asset("assets/images/MenuIconSelected.png"), height: screenHeight * 0.035,)
                  : Container(child: Image.asset("assets/images/MenuIconUnselected.png"), height: screenHeight * 0.035,)
                ),
              ]
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: <Widget>[
              HomeScreen(userInfo: widget.userInfo),
              SingleChildScrollView(child: RatingScreen()),
              OptionsScreen(userInfo: widget.userInfo)
            ])
          )
        ])
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RatingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Background(),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: screenWidth * 0.11,
                  top: screenHeight * 0.005,
                  right: screenWidth * 0.11
                ),
                child: TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontFamily: "Gentium Book Basic"
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                    filled: true,
                    hintText: "Sometext...",
                    errorMaxLines: 2,
                    errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.red),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: screenWidth * 0.02),
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontFamily: "Gentium Book Basic"
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0)
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0)
                    ),
                    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0)
                    ),
                    focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0)
                    )
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

[image: TextField]

[image: TabScreen]

[image: Error1]

[image: Error2]

By the way, my "Background" class that I use on each one of my classes It's the only one that contains a "Paint" class. I post it just in case there is correlation between the first line of my error and the class.

```
class Background extends StatelessWidget {
  ///Methods
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: BackgroundWave(),
      ),
    );
  }//End of build()
}

class BackgroundWave extends CustomPainter {
    
  ///Methods
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
    ..shader = ui.Gradient.linear(
          Offset(0.0, size.height), 
          Offset(size.width, size.height),
          [
            Color(0xFF51E598), 
            Color(0xFF4599E1)
          ],
          [0.0, 0.8]
        )
    ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
    ..strokeWidth = 2.0;

    Path path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, size.height * 0.45); //Point A
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.30, size.height * 0.56, 
      size.width * 0.50, size.height * 0.43); //Point B to C
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.70, size.height * 0.32,
        size.width * 1.0, size.height * 0.43); //Point D to E


    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint); 
  }//End of paint()

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }//End of shouldRepaint()
  
}
```

I will appreciate if someone can help me, I have been struggling with this error for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have provided enough width and height to the parent widget containing the image, and it is not going infinite